# Share files with external user in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-users, azure-ad

When you share a PDF file which is inside a SharePoint online directory with a External User (those that use a Micrososft account not those that use organizational account from another tenant).

Does it mean that the user has been added to your Azure AD automatically?

Comment: Have you checked your Azure AD after adding an external user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and they show up as active (Unlicensed) users in you Admin Center [https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home#/users].

You will see them with their full e-mail address (@-sign changed to underscore _) like this:

```
name.lastName_gmail.com#EXT#@tenantName.onmicrosoft.com
```

So technically they are a part of Azure AD which controls authentication in you Office 365 tenant.

Comment: Ok, Thank you. So if I only share a file with an external user, he/she can be authenticated by our Azure AD to access Applications that are accessible using OAuth or OpenID?

Comment: @Medes You're welcome! When the external user have accepted the invitation. Before that there are no records in Azure AD.

Comment: Yes I meant when the external user have accepted the invitation, So the answer is YES. The user can even access all those applicatians that are secured using OAuth based on our Azure AD.

Comment: @Medes True that! :)